# How to get latest and earliest from a django QuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

In my django app, there are a few different ways that I get a QuerySet object of the same model.

I would like to use one function to render the data -- and this has been working fine, until I decided to add both **earliest** and **latest** time to display on top of the list.

Here's my latest attempt:

```
def render_list(request, objList):
    latest = earliest = None
    if objList:
        latest = objList.latest('time').time
        earliest = objList.earliest('time').time

    context = {'objList': objList,
               'earliest': earliest,
               'latest': latest,
               }
    return render(request, 'list.html', context)
```

This produces the error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot reverse a query once a slice has been taken.
```

Is there a way to get around this problem?

**More details:**
The function `render_list` is being called by multiple view functions in `views.py`, for example :

```
def list_all(request):
    objList = MyTable.objects.order_by('ip')
    return render_list(request,objList)

def detail(request, ip, group):
    objList = MyTable.objects
    try:
        item = MyTable.objects.get(ip=ip)
        # display the details page...

    except MyTable.DoesNotExist:
        objList = MyTable.objects.complex_filter(...)
        # more code
        # ...
        return render_list(request, objList)
```

and corresponding lines in `urls.py`

```
path('list', views.list_all)
path('<group>/<ip>', views.detail)
```

Comment: What is `objList` here? And this looks like a view function (since its first argument is called `request` and it returns a rendered template) - how are you passing what appears to be a complex object (not a simple string or number) as part of the URL?

Comment: this is a function that is being called by multiple view functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to get around this error is to use `latest()` and `earliest()` (as well as `first()` and `last()` only on querysets that haven't been sliced (e.g. using `queryset[:5]` to get the top five records). You `objList` seems to have been sliced before it was passed to the function.

If you have a queryset that has the records in the correct order (meaning that the earliest and latest are first and last), you have two more options:

1. Use three additional queries to get the first and last record:

```
earliest = objList[0]
latest = objList[objList.count()]
```

2. Instantiate the objects in the queryset (calling `len` on it does that). Then you can access the first and last item without additional queries:

```
latest = objList[len(objList)-1]
earliest = objList[0]
```

This needs only one query, but it loads all objects in the queryset into memory.

To repeat, this only works if the queryset is ordered so as to have `earliest` and `latest` first and last. Otherwise you have to define separate querysets.

Comment: Some view functions that call `render_list` slice the queryset, and the order is different...

Comment: I figured out I can pass extra arguments to `render_list`, and do any necessary slicing there. Thanks!